# 4 lists into a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have 4 lists;

```
[1,3,6][1,5,9][1,2,4]['A','B','C']
```

I want to create one list of tuples like so

```
[(1,1,1,'A'),(3,5,2,'B'),(6,9,4,'C')]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the built-in zip function:

```
>>> zip([1,3,6],[1,5,9],[1,2,4],['A','B','C'])
[(1, 1, 1, 'A'), (3, 5, 2, 'B'), (6, 9, 4, 'C')]
```

It works with other iterables too.